# Does Protractor Automation Support Devextereme controls

Tags: protractor

My team has used devexterme controls in Angular application. And I have to implement Protractor Automation Testing on same project. So the query is, does protractor support all the devexterme controls?

Thanks in Advance!

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Seems that https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700443 answers to your question.

Moreover there were not any issues related to Devextreme on protractor github.